# How to preview API JSON response in swagger when using content-disposition: attachment; filename="api.json"

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am using Java, Swagger 2.

I need to use `content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.json"` in the response header of the APIs but when I use this header, I see the Download file button link and the file includes the response. When I use the APIs in UI(React) or any other rest API client, I get JSON response rather than download file link which is expected.

[image]

This is how I am setting header in CORS filter.

```
private void setHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.json\"");
  }
```

Setting `application/json`

```
@GetMapping(path="/xyz", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

I want swagger also to preview the response JSON rather than showing up the Download link button.

Answer (score 0):

notice you are using content-disposition "attachment", which tells the browser to serve a file and download it (open a dialog of where to save the file most of the times). if you want the browser to try and parse the file you are serving - use content-disposition "inline".

about swagger - you want to show matching behavior between swagger and the real API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition